# Rotate QPixmap on a QGraphicsScene around a point

Tags: qt, qt5

My problem is the following:
I have a QGraphicsScene, there is a QPixmap on it. I would like to rotate that pixmap around a center point, would work like a clock actually.

I've tried these:í

```
QPixmap pointer_pixmap("/home/peter/desktop/myimg2.png");
QTransform transform;

QGraphicsPixmapItem *pointer = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pointer_pixmap);
pointer->setOffset(174,190);
pointer->setTransformOriginPoint(QPoint(174-pointer_pixmap.width(), 190-pointer_pixmap.height()));


transform.translate((174-pointer_pixmap.width())/2,(190-pointer_pixmap.height())/2);
transform.rotate(60);
transform.translate(-((174-pointer_pixmap.width())/2),-((190-pointer_pixmap.height())/2));

pointer_pixmap = pointer_pixmap.transformed(transform);

item->addItem(pointer);

pointer->setPixmap(pointer_pixmap);
```

It looks like the translation doesn't have any effect on my pixmap. Why's that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should rotate the `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, not the pixmap itself.
Use [`QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformOriginPoint) to define the transform origin point and [`QGraphicsItem::setRotation`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation) to rotate the item.

Comment: It seems to work, but how could I do that in a loop, I mean rotate my image like a clock pointer.
It rotates only once.

Comment: @erbal Don't do it in a loop, it will block the event loop. Use `QTimer` that you connect to a slot where you rotate the item.

Comment: @erbal Also you must increase the rotation each time. Doing `setRotation(10)` twice will not rotate it 20 degrees, it will only rotate it 10 degrees once.

Comment: Yes, I've rewritten the relevant codes. It works like a charm now. :)